# How to define the name of a service in grails?

Tags: grails

In grails when you create a service, it has the name of the class. So If I create CategoryService, in a controller, I add 'def categoryService' in the controller.

But how to define a name different of the class. Sample : 'mycategorySvc'?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You would have to wire it up yourself in the spring/resources.groovy file.  That said, I wouldn't recommend doing this sort of thing for a couple of reasons

1. Shortening the word Service to Svc doesn't gain you anything
2. Other grails developers looking at your code in 6 months will say "WTF?"

I'd like to hear an argument for MyCategorySvc over MyCategoryService.

And BTW, the first bit doesn't matter (MyCatagory).  It doesn't have to match the domain.  The only thing required for auto injection is the word Service at the end.  You can create a service called JooHooBooDooService and throw it in the CategoryController just fine.

Comment: Yes your right but it's because a bug exist in Grails with some service. I get the error mypackage.MyCategoryService cannot be cast with mypackage.MyCategoryService

Comment: What version of grails and can you be more descriptive about the bug?

Comment: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7302 I have the same message and I use the code with @Transactional. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are facing some other casting issue but just to answer the question.
The way of doing this is to define our bean in resources.groovy.

Assume I have **QuestionAnswerService** instead of **questionAnswerService** name I wanted **qns**, so I will define **qns bean in resources.groovy**

```
 beans = {
    qns(QuestionAnswerService){ 
    }
 }
```

and just inject my service with this name in any controller and service like

```
def qns
```

that's it, I have qns named QuestionAnswerService bean injected

Hope it helps. Thanks